# HTML title tag empty for categories and products with custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, catalog

I'm having a strange problem where the `<title>` element has no content for category or product pages.

Other pages work as expected.

On product pages the social graph tags (eg, `og:title`) do contain the correct values.

Where this gets confusing for me is the `<title>` element has a value if I use the Blank or Luma themes - it is only empty in my custom theme.

If I fill in SEO attribute values for a product that will show up for the `<title>` element for my theme, but that's not practical as there are over 8000 products to update. It works for the pre-provided themes anyway, so I feel like there is something else going on...

Has anyone else seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 1):

My theme removes the `breadcrumbs` block, this in turn breaks `<title>` values for products and categories.

Comment: An easy fix for this is to extend the template (Magnto_Theme/templates/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml) in your custom theme but leve it empty. This will stop breadcrumbs from displaying but keep the titles working.